# how to drop a mysql database which is having numbers

Tags: mysql, database, drop-database

I created a mysql database with name 123, when i want to drop it,it is not dropping and throwing error. I used query.   DROP DATABASE 123;  and also tried DROP DATABASE '123';  . The other databases with name like ABC123 are dropping. Any solution would be greatful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
DROP DATABASE `123`
```

You need to put the name inside the backticks.

Comment: working. thanks for backticks.  I was doing with single quotes.. thats why i got error. when used with backticks database has dropped.

Comment: @AnilkumarKun:- You are welcome. On a side note: Never use such database names in future. It would be confusing as well as it will create troubles for you. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

You should never choose such names for DB or tables, however you can drop the database as

```
DROP DATABASE `123`
```

Need to use backticks for the db name

Comment: working. thanks for backticks.  I was doing with single quotes.. thats why i got error. when used with backticks database has dropped.